# Form API - Ajax vs. Wrapper

Tags: forms, ajax, taxonomy-terms

I have 3 Dropdown Fields which reload "in a row"

```
$form = array();
 $form['oid'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Operating System'),
'#options' => taas_select_options_os_frontend(),
'#required' => true,
'#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'browser-wrapper',
    'callback' => 'taas_ajax_browserlist',
    'method' => 'replace',
  )
);

$form['bid'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Browser'),
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('Select OS First'))),
'#required' => true,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="browser-wrapper">', 
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#ajax' => array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'flash-wrapper',
            'callback' => 'taas_ajax_flashlist',
            'method' => 'replace',
        ), );
```

after Refresh of the BID field the old name and id of the  are gone and so the eventlistner isn't working any more

```
function taas_ajax_browserlist($form, $form_state){
  $os = isset($form_state['values']['oid']) ? $form_state['values']['oid'] : 'os';

  switch($os){
      case 'os': break;
      default: 
          $form['bid'] = array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => t('Browser'),
          '#options' => taas_select_options_browser_frontend($os),
          '#required' => true,
          '#prefix' => '<div id="browser-wrapper">', 
          '#suffix' => '</div>',            
        );
  }
  return $form['bid'];
}
```

And before somebody asks ;) I don't want to use the hierachical-select module if possible

After Ajax reload select field looses its attributes

Before:
    
    Internet-Browser *
    - Auswahl -Select OS     First

after ajax callback

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select">
  <label>Internet-Browser <span class="form-required" title="Diese Angabe wird benötigt.">*     </span></label>
 <select class="form-select required"><option value="1">Chrome-16-0-9-12</option><option value="2">FF-3-6</option></select>
```

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: no javaskript works fine, is maybe a bad way of thinking or a "bug" in the replacement api

Comment: i figured out that the <select id="" name=""> transforms into <select> so that the eventtriger on the select name doesn't work anymore